# zend, remove require=true from jquery

Tags: jquery, zend-framework, input, onchange, required

I need to change the requirment of an input when a select change.
I have this declaration on my form:

```
$name = $this->addElement('text', 'name', array(
                'required' => true,
                'label' => 'Name',
                'filters'    => array('StringTrim'),
            ));
```

I try with jquery in phtml file (view) :

```
$('#select').change(function(){
    $('#name').prop('disabled', true);
})
```

but not work, the input continue to be required.
Anyone can heklp me?

Stefania

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must remove required from the PHP side.

I can propose you this:

1. In your form, add an hidden element like this:

   ```
   $change_select = new Zend_Form_Element_Hidden('change_select');
    $this->addElement($change_select);
   ```
2. In your javascript :

   ```
   $('#select').change(function(){
       $("#change_select").val("change");
   })
   ```
3. In your controller, try something like this:

   ```
   // $form  is your form in your controller like : 
   // this $form = new Application_Form_Album();

   if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
       $formData = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
       if ($formData['change_select'] == 'change'){
           $form->getElement('name')->setRequired(false);
       }
       if ($form->isValid($formData)) {
           ....
   ```

Comment: it works partially,. It looks like a non required but the the system continue to diplay error message and not apply the requirement

Comment: there are no errors, only the system not see the rule and continue to pretend the input

Comment: curious, i try it and it work for me. Add debug message to see $formData['change_select']  value in PHP side and $("#change_select") in js side

Comment: Great, I am reassured! :) Thank's for your return. Good Luck.

Comment: Can you validate the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove `required` attribute

```
$('#select').change(function(){
    $('#name').removeProp('required');
})
```

Comment: could you please share html code. Share jsfiddle link with your problem statement if possible.